# Hiding implementation of members owned by PImpl-objects

Tags: c++, design-patterns, interface, shared-libraries, pimpl-idiom

I have a class which I want to create an interface for without showing any of the implementation (not because it's closed source, but because of a lot of unnecessary headers such as OpenGL coming with it), let's call that class Foo. I know this is commonly done through either the PImpl-idiom or virtual interfaces, and I've implemented the PImpl-idiom for that class.

However, this class has public functions which returns other classes that are also including those headers, so obviously I can't return those objects as-is as that'd require me to include headers I don't want to include in Foo.h. However, these classes are used internally within the library a lot, and thus I don't want to implement them with PImpl as that'd introduce a lot of overhead (they're used a lot within a 3D renderer's code). Let's call one of them Bar:

Foo.h:

```
#include "Bar.h"

class Foo
{

private:
    class impl;

    std::unique_ptr<impl> m_pimpl;

public:
    Foo();
    Bar& get_bar();
};
```

Foo.cpp:

```
#include "Foo.h"

class Foo::impl {
private:
    Bar m_bar;

public:
    Bar& get_bar();
};

Foo::Foo() : m_pimpl{std::make_unique<impl>()} 
{ }

Bar& Foo::get_bar() {
    return m_pimpl->get_bar();
}
```

For this to work I need to #include "Bar.h", but Bar.h might include headers I want to hide. This leaves me with the option to make Bar use the PImpl-idiom as well, but I don't want that overhead for Bar because Bar is used a lot internally within Foo. However, I figured a way to solve this, but I'm not very sure about it as I haven't seen it used anywhere before:

Using PImpl without an owning pointer/reference to simply wrap a class and create a interface for it. This way the overhead only applies when *outside* of Foo, but internally it'll still use the non-wrapped class.

For example, let's say PBar is wrapping Bar:

PBar.h:

```
class Bar;

class PBar {
private:
    Bar &m_bar;

public:
    explicit PBar(Bar &bar);
    void do_stuff();
};
```

PBar.cpp:

```
#include "PBar.h"

#include "../impl/Bar.h" // This is the actual Bar implementation


PBar::PBar(Bar &bar) : m_bar(bar) {

}

void PBar::do_stuff() {
    m_bar.do_stuff();
}
```

And Foo instantiates PBar on creation with a reference to the actual Bar inside the object:

Foo.h

```
#include "PBar.h"

class Foo
{

private:
    class impl;
    std::unique_ptr<impl> m_pimpl;
    PBar m_bar;

public:
    Foo();
    PBar& get_bar() { return m_bar; }
};
```

Foo.cpp:

```
class Foo::impl {
private:
    Bar m_bar;

public:
    Bar& get_bar();
};

Foo::Foo() : m_pimpl{std::make_unique<impl>()},
             m_bar(impl->get_bar())
{ }
```

Is this pattern ever used? Are there any other ways I can solve this problem? It's more or less the same principle as PImpl, but is there anything bad about it I haven't yet thought about? It definitely feels even less clean, but I can't see how this could be done in any other way.

Also, I want neither PBar or Bar to be constructable outside of Foo, so that's not a problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot (should not) change the object referenced by a reference member: how do you do here: `Foo a,b; a=b;` (supposing you initialize a non null unique_ptr). This is easily corrected replacing the reference by a pointer.

This look like a good idea, what you do is caching a dereferencement. But you are loosing some efficiency of the pimpl idiom and you are doubling the size of `Foo`.

Have you thought in making the `class impl` standard layout and putting `Bar` at a known offset inside `impl`:

Foo.h

```
constexpr auto impl_bar_offset = 8;
//...
class Foo{
  private:
    class impl;
    std::unique_ptr<impl> m_impl;
  public:
    bar& get_bar(){
       assert(m_impl);
       return *reinterpret_cast<bar*>(
         reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(m_impl.get())+impl_bar_offset);
    }
 };
```

Foo.cpp

```
class impl{
  long a_long;
  bar a_bar;
  //...
  };
static_assert(impl_bar_offset==offsetof(impl,a_bar));
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I hadn't thought about that, but if I were to use something that requires me to manually set some offset/size, I'd just go for the "fast pimpl" idiom instead and gain efficiency AND not have to worry about interfaces! (http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/028.htm)

Comment: I think this is out of the subject but this is still interesting, bonne chance jeune graçon!